# Regex in fail2ban not matching

Tags: regex

Should be a simple thing, but with regex nothing is simple.

My fail2ban filter for wordpress sites:

```
[Definition]
#failregex = <HOST>.*POST.*(wp-login\.php|xmlrpc\.php).* 200
#failregex = <HOST>.*POST.*(wp-login\.php|xmlrpc\.php).* 200[ 0-9]*
failregex = ^"<HOST> .* "POST .*wp-login.php

#failregex = <HOST>.*POST.*wp-login.php .*
#failregex = ^"<HOST> .* "POST .*(wp-login.php|xmlrpc.php) HTTP/.*" (200|401)
ignoreregex =
```

As you can see I have tested multiple things, but I just don't get a match. Odly I do get a match on regex101.

And this is my logfile (those entires should be found):

```
"hostname 172.70.34.43 - - [18/May/2021:05:58:22 +0000] "POST //wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3069"
"hostname 172.70.34.43 - - [18/May/2021:05:58:22 +0000] "POST //wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3069"
"hostname 172.70.34.43 - - [18/May/2021:05:58:21 +0000] "POST //wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3069"
```

The logfile could also contain entries like this:

```
"hostname 172.69.63.84 - - [19/May/2021:09:23:01 +0000] "GET /feed/ HTTP/1.1" 200 14872"
"hostname 172.69.63.84 - - [19/May/2021:09:23:00 +0000] "GET /feed HTTP/1.1" 301 0"
"hostname 162.158.91.10 - - [19/May/2021:09:23:01 +0000] "POST /wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1621416181.1017169952392578125000 HTTP/1.1" 200 0"
"hostname 172.68.57.138 - - [19/May/2021:09:22:34 +0000] "GET /versand/ HTTP/1.1" 200 27456"
"hostname 172.68.110.69 - - [19/May/2021:09:22:34 +0000] "POST /wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1621416154.5001699924468994140625 HTTP/1.1" 200 0"
"hostname 172.69.34.217 - - [19/May/2021:09:19:48 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 32986"
```

And I have tested with fail2ban-regex, but with no success. I have also tried to replace < HOST > with the actual hostname, but in this case fail2ban will not accept the regex.

```
Running tests                                                                                           
=============                                                                                           
                                                                                                        
Use   failregex filter file : wordpress, basedir: /etc/fail2ban                                         
Use         log file : /home/runcloud/logs/tmp.log                                                      
Use         encoding : UTF-8                                                                            
                                                                                                        
                                                                                                        
Results                                                                                                 
=======                                                                                                 
                                                                                                        
Failregex: 0 total                                                                                      
                                                                                                        
Ignoreregex: 0 total                                                                                    
                                                                                                        
Date template hits:                                                                                     
|- [# of hits] date format                                                                              
|  [3] Day(?P<_sep>[-/])MON(?P=_sep)ExYear[ :]?24hour:Minute:Second(?:\.Microseconds)?(?: Zone offset)? 
`-                                                                                                      
                                                                                                        
Lines: 3 lines, 0 ignored, 0 matched, 3 missed
```

Comment: pleas add example that you want match with your regex? simple unambiguous name, like: That must be found.

Comment: from my logfile: these three lines should be found

Comment: and an example that not should by matched please (so that we could see the difference)

Comment: I have added some more data

Comment: so simply check if the number 3069? is in?

Comment: now, it should check if it's a POST request on either wp-login.php or xmlrp.php

Comment: "POST\b.+\b(wp-login|xmlrp)\.php

Answer (score 0):

this regex match (in this example the first 3 lines)
"POST request on either `wp-login.php` or `xmlrp.php`" as [rapsli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67581400/regex-in-fail2ban-not-matching/67601638#comment119487038_67581400) wanted

`"POST\b.+\b(wp-login|xmlrp)\.php`

in

```
"hostname 172.70.34.43 - - [18/May/2021:05:58:22 +0000] "POST //wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3069"
"hostname 172.70.34.43 - - [18/May/2021:05:58:22 +0000] "POST //wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3069"
"hostname 172.70.34.43 - - [18/May/2021:05:58:21 +0000] "POST //wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 3069"
"hostname 172.69.63.84 - - [19/May/2021:09:23:01 +0000] "GET /feed/ HTTP/1.1" 200 14872"
"hostname 172.69.63.84 - - [19/May/2021:09:23:00 +0000] "GET /feed HTTP/1.1" 301 0"
"hostname 162.158.91.10 - - [19/May/2021:09:23:01 +0000] "POST /wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1621416181.1017169952392578125000 HTTP/1.1" 200 0"
"hostname 172.68.57.138 - - [19/May/2021:09:22:34 +0000] "GET /versand/ HTTP/1.1" 200 27456"
"hostname 172.68.110.69 - - [19/May/2021:09:22:34 +0000] "POST /wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1621416154.5001699924468994140625 HTTP/1.1" 200 0"
"hostname 172.69.34.217 - - [19/May/2021:09:19:48 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 32986"
```

https://regexr.com/5t8e3

Comment: doesn't seem to work with fail2ban. While the regex might be ok, fail2ban doesn't pick it up
user@vultr:/etc/fail2ban/filter.d# fail2ban-regex /home/runcloud/logs/tmp.log wordpress

Running tests
=============

Use   failregex filter file : wordpress, basedir: /etc/fail2ban
ERROR: No failure-id group in '"POST\b.+\b(wp-login|xmlrp)\.php'

Answer (score 0):

needs to stand for the place with the IP. So this regex should work with fail2ban

```
failregex = "[a-z]* <HOST>.*(wp-login\.php|xmlrpc.php).*
```